# What's the general procedure to analyse a function to find roots using numerical methods and sketch the graph?

Tags: calculus, functions, numerical-methods

When I'm facing functions for which no formula exist to calculate the roots directly, what can I do with calculus to analyse it so that I can obtain information about the function's behavior?

Suppose that the function is $f(x) = e^{-x} + x^3$. The first thing that I'd check is whether the function changes its sign between $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. In this case it goes to $+\infty$ for both sides, so I can't guarantee the existance of roots relying on that alone.

The next step would be to take the derivatives. Calculating $f'''$ gives me that $f'''$ is monotone crescent and I can see that there is a root for that function. To find this root I can use Newton's method.

From there I'm kinda cluless about what to do with the information given by the third order derivative. I don't know how many times $0 = e^{-x} + x^3$ happen, is there a theorem to find this out?

Comment: Your function takes negative values for some small negative $x$. For example, $f(-3)\approx -7$. Since it blows up for $\pm\infty$ you can at least guarantee the _existance_ of two real roots. Here is a [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x^3%2Be^%28-x%29+from+x%3D-6+to+x%3D2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Newton's Method to find the zeros and sketch the graph of $f(x) = e^{-x} + x^3$

This is the series of steps I've taken to tackle this exercise:

Everything I've done with the derivatives is supported by the fact that $f$ is continuous and continuously differentiable.

1. Calculate derivatives (*in this exercise it's feasible because I needed derivatives up to third order. However, I think it's unfesiable if the function has higher degrees as I'd need to compute too many derivatives by hand*).

$$\begin{aligned} 
f'(x) &= -e^{-x} + 3x^2\\
f''(x)  &= e^{-x} + 6x\\
f'''(x) &= -e^{-x} + 6
\end{aligned}$$

2. Study the sign of $f'''$

$f'''(x) = -e^{-x} + 6$ is monotonic crescent. To calculate its zero is the same as to calculate $e^{-x} = 6$, which can be rewriten as $\ln 6 = x$. So $x \approx -1.791759469$ (*this is the max number of significant figures my hand calculator has*)

$$\text{<-- negative }1.79 \text{ positive -->}$$

3. Study the sign of $f''$

From $f'''$ I know that $f''$ has one critical point.

Caculate $f''(-1.791759469) \approx -4.75055682$.

Calculate $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f''(x) = +\infty$$ $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f''(x) = +\infty$$

(*I can either assume that near infinity $e^x$ "wins" or take the ratio*)

Now I know that $f''$ has two zeros. Use Newton's Method to find them. From the study of $f'''$ I know that $f''$ doesn't have pathological points where Newton's Method fail, so I can choose any point but the critical one.

$$++++ (-2,83) ---- (-0.2) ++++$$

Those two points are both the critical points of $f'$ and the inflexion points of $f$.

3. Study the sign of $f'$

Calculate $$f'(-2,83) = 7.08$$
$$f'(-0.2) = -1.1$$

From $f'(-2,83)*f'(-0.2)<0$ I know that there is one zero in between $[-2.83, -0.2]$, and because those two points are the two critical points, there is just one zero.

Calculate $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f'(x) = +\infty$$ $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f'(x) = -\infty$$

Now I know that there are two more zeros.

$$---- (-3.73)++++(-0.91)----(0.45)++++$$

4. Finally, back to $f$.

From $f'$ I know that $f$ has three critical points.

$$f(-3.73) = -10.21$$
$$f(-0.91) = 1.73$$
$$f(0.45) = 0.72$$

Calculate $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$$ $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = +\infty$$

So between $[-3.73, -0.91]$ there is one zero and between $[-0.91, 0.45]$ there are none. There is another zero to the left of -3.73 because the function approaches infinity as $x \rightarrow -\infty$.

From $f(-0.91) * f(0.45) > 0$ and because $f$ approaches infinity as $x \rightarrow +\infty$, there are no zeros to the right of $x = 0.45$.

5. With all the information above I can now sketch the graph.

I'm not really sure about the mathematical rigor, because I just assumed some theorems as true and used its result. Moreover, I can forsee doubts in case the function's critical points are really close to the x axis, in which case precision is an issue. there is also one question that I didn't properly answer: how can I know whether the chosen point for Newton's Method is going to converge or diverge? In the above exercise I didn't face such points.

Comment: +1 for a very good alternate method AS LONG AS YOU CAREFULLY CHOOSE THE POINTS YOU'RE TESTING. If you choose points close to asymptotes,this method can self-destruct.But again,if you carefully choose the points, this works well.

Answer (score 1):

There are LOTS of ways to do this. The first thing you have to do is find out where the extrema are and if f is defined on a closed and bounded subset of the real line,then the extreme value theorem says f has absolute extrema on the subset. However,since you're assuming the function goes to infinity,this isn't an option-the domain is the whole real line. Since part of the function is an exponential,the simplest method would probably be a Taylor expansion of the function at a point x. This will give you the first and second derivatives,as well as the actual expansion at the point. At least,that's how I'd attack it.